# React SyntheticEvent warning being thrown even with e.persistent()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a couple blocks of code that sets the state of by the user enter a value into and input and even checking a checkbox. They are both throwing the classic `SyntheticEvent` warning:

`Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property buttons on a released/nullified synthetic event.`

I have tried `chacheing` and `e.persist()` and its still throwing the warning on the `onChange` events:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
   e.persist();
   const { name, checked } = e.target;
   setHolidayData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: checked }));
};

const updateValues = (e) => {
   e.persist();
   const { name, value } = e.target;
   setHolidayData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
};
```

These `change` events are on the `inputs` and `check boxes` respectively. What am i doing wrong here that the warnings are still being thrown?

Entire Component Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import _ from "lodash";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import MuiDialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import MuiDialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import MuiDialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';
import moment from 'moment';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

import * as actions from "../../../Redux/Actions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction="down" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

const styles = (theme) => ({
    root: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    closeButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: theme.spacing(1),
        top: theme.spacing(1),
        color: theme.palette.grey[500],
    },
});

const DialogTitle = withStyles(styles)((props) => {
    const { children, classes, onClose, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.root} {...other}>
            <Typography variant="h6">{children}</Typography>
            {onClose ? (
                <IconButton aria-label="close" className={classes.closeButton} onClick={onClose}>
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
            ) : null}
        </MuiDialogTitle>
    );
});

const DialogContent = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}))(MuiDialogContent);

const DialogActions = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}))(MuiDialogActions);

const HolidayDialog = (props) => {
    const [noticeModal, setNoticeModal] = useState(props.open);
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [holidayData, setHolidayData] = useState({});

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        setSelectedDate(moment(props.data.HolidayDate));
        setNoticeModal(props.open);
        setHolidayData(props.data);
    }, [props.open]);

    const user = useSelector(state => {
        return JSON.stringify(state.main.user);
    });

    const handleDateChange = (date) => {
        setSelectedDate(date);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        props.onClose(false);
        setNoticeModal(false);
    };

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        const { name, checked } = e.target;
        setHolidayData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: checked }));
    };

    const updateValues = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setHolidayData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
    };

    const formSubmit = () => {
        dispatch(actions.holiday_editHoliday(holidayData));
        handleClose();
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        dispatch(actions.holiday_submitHoliday(holidayData));
        handleClose();
    }

    const handleCreate = () => {
        let createdHoliday = {
            Active: true,
            Branch: holidayData.Branch ? holidayData.Branch : '',
            Close: holidayData.Close ? holidayData.Close : '',
            CoOp: holidayData.CoOp ? holidayData.CoOp : false,
            HolidayDate: selectedDate ? moment(selectedDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY') : moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
            HolidayName: holidayData.HolidayName ? holidayData.HolidayName : "",
            Open: holidayData.Branch ? holidayData.Branch : '',
            Phone: holidayData.Phone ? holidayData.Phone : true,
            Web: holidayData.Web ? holidayData.Web : true,
            Hours: holidayData.Hours ? holidayData.Hours : '',
        }
        dispatch(actions.holiday_createHoliday(createdHoliday));
        handleClose();
    }

    const handlePublish = () => {
        const userObj = JSON.parse(user);
        const userName = `CCU\\${userObj.UserName}`;
        if (userName != holidayData.SubmittedBy) {
            dispatch(actions.holiday_publishHoliday(holidayData));
            handleClose();
        } else {
            toast.error("Submitter & Publisher cannot be the same person", {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 5000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: false,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
            });
            handleClose();
        }
    }

    const handleDecline = () => {
        dispatch(actions.holiday_declineHoliday(holidayData));
        handleClose();
    }

    return (
        <Dialog
            open={noticeModal}
            TransitionComponent={Transition}
            keepMounted
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="notice-modal-slide-title"
            aria-describedby="notice-modal-slide-description"
        >
            <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
                {holidayData.HolidayName ? holidayData.HolidayName : 'Create New Holiday'}
            </DialogTitle>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off" id="HolidayForm" onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); formSubmit(); } }>
            <DialogContent dividers>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField required name="HolidayName" id="outlined-basic" label="Holiday Name" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.HolidayName || ''} disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" name="Branch" label="Branch" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.Branch || ''} disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row mt-3">
                        <div className="col">
                        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                            <KeyboardDatePicker
                                disableToolbar
                                variant="inline"
                                format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                margin="normal"
                                id="date-picker-inline"
                                label="Holiday Date *"
                                value={selectedDate}
                                onChange={handleDateChange}
                                KeyboardButtonProps={{
                                    'aria-label': 'change date',
                                }}
                                disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}
                            />
                        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" name="Hours" label="Hours" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.Hours || ''} disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {holidayData.Hours ? (
                        <div className="row mt-3">
                            <div className="col">
                                <TextField id="outlined-basic" name="Open" label="Open" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.Open || ''} disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                                <TextField id="outlined-basic" name="Close" label="Close" variant="outlined" onChange={updateValues} value={holidayData.Close || ''} disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div></div>
                    )}
                    <div className="row mt-3">
                        <div className="col d-flex flex-column">
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Web || false}
                                    value={holidayData.Web}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="Web"
                                    color="primary"
                                    disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}
                                />
                                }
                                label="Show on Web?"
                            />
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.CoOp || false}
                                    value={holidayData.CoOp}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="CoOp"
                                    color="primary"
                                    disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}
                                />
                                }
                                label="CoOp Holiday?"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col d-flex flex-column">
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Phone || false}
                                    value={holidayData.Phone}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    name="Phone"
                                    color="primary"
                                    disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}
                                />
                                }
                                label="Use in IVR?"
                            />
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={holidayData.Active || true}
                                    value={holidayData.Active}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    disabled 
                                    name="Active"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                                }
                                label="Active"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions className="d-flex">
                {holidayData.Submitted ? (
                        <div className="mr-auto">
                            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handlePublish}>
                               Publish
                           </Button>
                            <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary" className="ml-2" onClick={handleDecline}>
                               Decline
                           </Button> 
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className="mr-auto">
                                <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                                Submit
                           </Button> 
                        </div>
                   )}
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClose} color="default">
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                {holidayData.Active ? (
                        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" type="submit" form="HolidayForm" disabled={holidayData.Submitted != null}>
                            Update Holiday
                         </Button>
                    ) : (
                         <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleCreate} form="HolidayForm">
                            Create Holiday
                         </Button>
                    )}

            </DialogActions>
            </form>
        </Dialog>
    )
}

export default HolidayDialog;
```

Comment: can you create a demo on stackblitz or codesandbox and share the link?